# A couple of problems on set theoretic manipulations and / or percentages

Tags: arithmetic

Problem 1:

A public opinion poll shows that 93% of the people agree with the government on the first decision, 84% on the second, and 77% on the third, for the three decisions made by the government. At least what percentage of the population in question agreed with the government on all three decisions?

Problem 2:

If 70% of all the disabled war veterans of a country have lost an eye, 75% an ear, 80% an arm, and 85% a leg, then at least what percentage must have lost all four?

Comment: That has really nothing to do with set theory.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought it's an application of the number of elements in the intersection of a collection of finite sets.

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure. Not every problem involving sets is about set theory.

Comment: So, can you make any headway on either of these problems, Saaqib? It's easier to help you if we know where you're stuck. Do you know how to do a similar problem where there are only 2 percentages involved, instead of 3 or four?

Comment: If $|A|$ denotes the number of elements in a finite set $A$, then we can show that $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-\#|A\cap B|-|B\cap C|-|C\cap A|+|A\cap B\cap C|$, a number which must be between $0$ and $100$, where $|A|=93$ is to be the percentage value of people agreeing on the first decision etc. So $|A\cap B\cap C|\geq |A\cap B|+|B\cap C|+|C\cap A|-|A|-|B|-|C|$. Now we know that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A \cap B|$, which is again a non-negative number not exceeding $100$. So $|A\cap B|\geq |A|+|B|-100$, etc. Right?

Comment: Then I wonder which areas of mathematics could these two problems most properly belong?

Comment: Can someone please correct for me the symbols for the union and the intersection that I've used? I mean I've used $\cap$ to denote the intersection and $\cup$ to denote the union. However, the output isn't displaying as I'd intended it to.

Comment: You can try flagging for moderator attention to the formatting.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud: I attempted to fix your comment above, but felt it was necessary to changed the notation slightly, using $| \cdot |$ instead of $\#(\cdot)$ to denote the cardinality of a set.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  to have the fewest number that share all three or four characteristics, you want all the rest to be missing only one.  So for the first problem, assume all the ones that disagree on the first agree on the next two and so on.  What is the total number of disagreers?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get it.

Comment: Let's do it for just two characteristics.  Out of 15 people, 12 are under 60 and 10 live in the US.  What is the minimum number who are both under 60 and live in the US?  The most you can exclude are 3 who are over 60 and 5 who live elsewhere, so at least 7 are under 60 and live in the US.  You could have more if there are some who are both over 60 and live elsewhere.

Comment: Correct. So nice of you. I'll now start thinking along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:

First we try to estimate the percentage of people who have disagreed on at least one of the decisions: there are $7\%$ people who've disagreed on the first decision, $16\%$ on the second, and $26\%$ on the third. So, if no two of these three groups of disagreers have any members in common, then $7+16+26$ $=$ $49\%$ of the people have disagreed on at least one of the three decisions. However, the above three groups of disagreers may have members in common; so at most $49\%$ of the people have disagreed on at least one of the three decisions. Hence at least $51\%$ have agreed on all three decisions.

Problem 2:

Amongst the disabled veterans who have not lost all four of the limbs, we note that $30\%$ have not lost an eye, $25\%$ have not lost an ear, $20\%$ have not lost an arm, and $15\%$ have not lost a leg. So at most $30+25+20+15$ $=$ $90\%$ of the disabled veterans have not lost all four of the limbs. Hence at least $10\%$ have lost all four.

Is my reasoning correct? And if so, have I managed to arrive at the correct answer too?

Comment: Have I managed to arrive at the correct answer? If so, is my method also correct?